# Check if a string contain digits and dash

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I'm trying to find the right regex to grepl weather a string contains digits[0-9] and the special character "-" only.

ex,

```
str1="00-25" #TRUE
str2="0a-2" #FALSE
```

I have tried

```
grepl("[^[:digit:]|-]",str2)
#[1] TRUE
```

thoughts?

Comment: `grepl("^[0-9-]+$", str1)`

Comment: Packages like `stringi` or its wrapper `stringr` make such operations easier

Comment: Note that `^` used inside a character class negates it. So `[^[:digit:]|-]` tells to match anything which is not a digit, `-` or `|` (alternation sign in character class is interpreted literally).

Comment: If you want to use `:digit:` or other similar keyword, note that base R string functions generally require double brackets - `[[:digit:]]`. Compare `grepl("[:digit:]", "1"); grepl("[[:digit:]]", "1")`

Comment: Thanks! by the way, what's the +$ for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check if the string has only digit and -.

To create the ensemble, you need to use "[]" so :

```
[0-9-]
```

Now you want to check that every character of the string is in the ensemble you have created, in other term you want to **start**(^) and **finish**($) by this ensemble :

```
^[0-9-]$
```

Finally in the variable there is 1 or more character, so I use the "+" :

```
grepl("^[0-9-]+$",str)
```

Comment: "[0-9-]" is fine (no need to escape the hyphen as long as it is the final character in the character class. "[[:digit:]-]" will work as well.

Comment: yep, no need to escape - since it's not at the middle of a character class.